# Localize float values in zend form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, locale

i have a zend form with some float values and want to render them loaclized (e.g. 1.25 is 1,25 in EUR). I'd like to use $this->formText(...), but a looking through the code, i found no place where this localization could happen, because it just fetches the value from the form element. So i think my only options are:

1. Set the localized value into the form element:

   ```
   $formElem->setValue($this->numberFormat($formElem->getValue()));
   ```

   This looks is really dirty to me.
2. Render the input element manually:

   ```
   <input ... value="<?php echo $this->numberFormat($formElem->getValue())?>" />
   ```
3. Write my own viewhelper.

None of these options look optimal to me. The form is hydrated via $form->bind($myDoctrineEntyity). Is there a better way to localize values in zend form?